# Difference between standard and non-standard diagrams in Software engineering

Tags: client-server, uml, pipeline, software-design, dataflow-diagram

I am writing a documentation for my Software engineering subject. My project is on a Hospital Managements System. Here is the question that is making me confused.

> (2. Architectural design) Present the overall software architecture, stating whether it’s Layered,
> Repository, Client-Server, or Pipe and Filter architecture( – skim through pages 155 to 164 of our text
> reference book to see descriptions of these different architectures).
>  Describe and present it on a standard or non-standard diagram.

So what is the difference between standard and non-standard diagram?

Comment: Non-standard is anything that does not comply to the standard. What else? Ask your tutor _which_ standard to apply. If it's UML then the UML defines the standard. If it's SysML then it would be the SysML standard. And so on. There is no _the standard_.

Answer (score 2):

The question is indeed confusing, since it presents architectural models as if they were mutually exclusive (i.e. it can be at the same time layered and client-server) and relies on ambiguous terminology.

When it comes to architectural diagrams, there are standard diagrams, which follow a well known formal graphical notation. Typical examples are:

- [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)
- Older OO notation (e.g. Booch, Rumbaugh or Objectory - it's really old because these have been merged together to make UML).
- Non OO notations,  such for example the [IDEF suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEF) (which was enriched in the meantime with an OO layer), SADT,  Gane & Sarson  (it's also quite old, less and less used, except in some niche markets).

Among those, the only which qualifies officially and unambiguously as a standard is UML:  it's the only one that is recognized by an international standard setting body ([ISO/IEC 19505](https://www.iso.org/standard/52854.html)).

But in architecture you have also a fair bunch of non-standard diagrams that convey  graphically the structural intent. Typically, a [layered arrangement of services](https://medium.com/@priyalwalpita/software-architecture-patterns-layered-architecture-a3b89b71a057),  or an [hexagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) or a [concentric presentations](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2008/07/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) are frequently used. Sometimes it's even more visual with clients shown as PC, and several servers in the network.  All these use non-standard notations.

Comment: I always admire this kind of response when myself I cannot say more than something like "standard and non standard cannot be compared", UV

Comment: UML is not the only one. Another well known official standard for architectural diagrams is ArchiMate, a standard maintained by the Open Group.